# Proving $\cup A_m$ $\subseteq$ B

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, inequality

Trying to prove $\cup A_m$ $\subseteq$ B where $$\cup A_m=\{(x,y) \in R^2|0 \lt y \le \frac{-m}{4}x^2+m\}$$ $$B=\{(x,y) \in R^2 | -2 \lt x \lt2 \land y\gt0\}$$So my first step in proving $\cup A_m$ $\subseteq B$ was to set $0 \lt \frac{-m}{4}x^2+m$ and solve for $x$. When I did that I got $\pm2\lt x$. Does that translate to $-2 \lt x \lt 2$?

Comment: Saying $\pm 2<x$ is not good, you have $4>x^2\implies 2>|x|\implies -2<x<2$(note we are assuming $m>0$, aslo note it is not a question about set theory but a question about solving $0 \lt \frac{-m}{4}x^2+m$)

Comment: @Holo that's backwards, $4 \lt x^2$

Comment: nope, we are multiplying by $-1/m<0$ which reverse the inequality